# How can I get my PBI report to populate each query result on a new page?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Relative NEWB to PowerBI report builder and have a question about report iteration. Basically, I have a dataset that contains data for 'scorecards'. I want each page of the report to be one 'scorecard'. This corresponds to each row in my dataset query accordingly. I formatted my report accordingly and was anticipating that when I linked each textbox to its corresponding dataset field, when I run the report, I would have a multi-page report; however, I'm only seeing the first query result. I'm assuming this has something to do with the first() function. What am I missing?

*edit* - I'm basically trying to recreate the functionality of an Access 'report' where each record is displayed on a new report page.

[image: Access Example]

[image: Text Box value]

[image: Form design]

[image: Dataset]

Comment: What is PowerBI report generator? Do you mean PowerBI Desktop?

Comment: They are two separate applications. Sorry, it's report 'builder'.

Comment: Are you using "Power BI Report Builder" ?

Comment: Yes, that is what it is called.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured this out - it was staring right in front of me! I needed to add a 'List' data region. I can then design the report and it creates a new page for each record.

Comment: Did you create a paginated report?